# updating many rows using ajax .serializeArray()

Tags: php, ajax, sql-update

I have one problem it's kinda strange, I have one sale receipt which contains 66 rows of data, now I want to update a receipt when I fetch data from the table is shows all record perfectly. but when I try to update rows in table it works fine till record number 58, but after that it gives me "undefined offset 58" error, it will bet update rows after index 58. Please can anyone help me it's been two days I am working on it but have not got a solution.

this is my code for sending the data to Ajax page using .serializeArray()

```
       $('#submit').on('click',function(){
        if($('#partnumber_1').val()=='' || 
       ($('.quantitytak').val()==0&& $('.quantity').val()==0)){
                swal("هەموو خانەکان داخل بکە","هەلە","warning");
           }else{
        $.ajax({
            url: "edit_sale_ajax.php?request=2",
            type: 'post',
            data: $('#form1').serializeArray(),
            success: function (data) {
                swal(data);
                $( "#invoice" ).prop( "disabled", false );
                 window.reload();
            }
        });
      }
        return false;  
    });
```

and this is my code for updating record in the table

```
    if($_GET['request']==2){
       $date = $_POST['order_date'];        
       $cus_name = $_POST['cus_name'];
       $recipt_no = $_POST['recipt_no'];
       $total_all = $_POST['total_all'];
       $total_loan=$_POST['total_load'];
       $discount=$_POST['discount'];
       $totalafterdis=$_POST['totalafterdis'];
       $paid_money = $_POST['money_paid'];
       $loan_now=$_POST['loan_now'];
       $partnumber = $_POST['partnumber'];
       $pricekarton = $_POST['pricekarton'];
       $pricetdana= $_POST['pricedana'];
       $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
       $number_inkarton = $_POST['danaynawkarton'];
       $total_dana = $_POST['totaldana'];
       $kartonbefor=$_POST['kartonbefore'];
       $danabefor = $_POST['danabefore'];
       $hamwbefore = $_POST['hamwbefore'];
       $sale_de_id = $_POST['detail_id'];
       $prev_id = $_POST['pro_id'];
       $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
       $quantitytak = $_POST['quantitytak'];
       $sub_total = $_POST['total'];        
       $remain_purchase = $_POST['remain_purchase'];
       $sale_id=$_POST['sale_id'];
       $today=date('Y-m-d h:i:sa');
       $loan_id=$_POST['loan_id'];
       $user_id=$_SESSION['userid'];
       $row=$_POST['row'];                    
          try {
                $flag = true;
                 $message = "";
                 $dbh->beginTransaction();
                 $sql_update_sale = "update sale_tbl set                              
                 sale_reciept_no=?,sale_date=?,total_befordis=?,             
                 discoun =?,  total_afterdic=?, sale_paid_money=?,     
                 customer_id=?,user_id=? where sale_id=$sale_id";
                 $query = $dbh->prepare($sql_update_sale);
                 $query->bindParam(1, $recipt_no, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                 $query->bindParam(2, $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                 $query->bindParam(3, $total_all, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                 $query->bindParam(4, $discount, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                 $query->bindParam(5, $totalafterdis,PDO::PARAM_STR 
                  );
                 $query->bindParam(6, $paid_money, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                 $query->bindParam(7, $cus_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                 $query->bindParam(8, $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);       
                   if (!$query->execute()) {
                      $flag = false;
                      print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
                      $message .= "error la update sale" . 
                        }
         for ($i = 1; $i <= $row; $i++) {
           var_dump($partnumber[$i]);
            $sql_update_sale_detail = "update sale_detail_tbl set                   
         product_id='$product_id[$i]',pricekarton='$pricekarton[$i]' 
        , pricedana= '$pricetdana[$i]', sale_kartonquantity=    
        '$quantity[$i]', sale_danaquantity='$quantitytak[$i]', 
         sub_total='$sub_total[$i]' where 
         sale_id='$sale_id' and sale_de_id='$sale_de_id[$i]' ";
         $statement = $dbh->prepare($sql_update_sale_detail);
             if (!$statement->execute()) {
                  $flag = false;
                  $m = print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
                  $message .= "error la update sale detail<br>" . 
                    }
                 //checking if product exist in stock table
                 $check_product = "SELECT product_id FROM stock_tbl 
                 where product_id='$product_id[$i]'";
                  $pro_check_ex = $dbh->prepare($check_product);
                   $pro_check_ex->execute();
                    if ($pro_check_ex->rowCount() >= 1) {
                    $hamwfater[$i] = intval($quantity[$i]) * 
                    intval($number_inkarton[$i]) + 
                    intval($quantitytak[$i]);
                    //if product still same product
                     if ($prev_id[$i] == $product_id[$i]) {
                        $kartontaza[$i] = $quantity[$i] - 
                         $kartonbefor[$i];
                        $danataza[$i] = $quantitytak[$i] - 
                         $danabefor[$i];
                         $hamwtaza[$i] = $hamwfater[$i] - 
                         $hamwbefore[$i];
                     $update_stock2 = "UPDATE stock_tbl SET 
                     quantitystock_karton=(quantitystock_karton- 
                     $kartontaza[$i]), quantitystock_tak=  
                     (quantitystock_tak-$danataza[$i]), 
                     total_quantity=(total_quantity- 
                     $hamwtaza[$i]),last_update='$date', 
                     pricekarton_instock= $pricekarton[$i], 
                     pricetak_instock=$pricetdana[$i] where 
                     product_id=$product_id[$i]";
                     $exe_update2= $dbh->prepare($update_stock2);
                      if (!$exe_update2->execute()) {
                         $flag = false;
                       $message .= "error la update stock yaksanan";
                        }
                        } else {
                      //if product changes in the list
                      $kartontaza[$i] = $quantity[$i];
                      $danataza [$i]= $quantitytak[$i];
                      $hamwtaza [$i]= $hamwfater[$i];
                  $update_stock1 = "UPDATE stock_tbl SET 
                  quantitystock_karton=quantitystock_karton+ 
                  $kartonbefor[$i],quantitystock_tak=quantitystock_tak 
                  +$danabefor[$i],total_quantity= 
                  total_quantity+$hamwbefore[$i],last_update=$date 
                  where product_id=$prev_id[$i]";
                  $exe_update1 = $dbh->prepare($update_stock1);
                   if (!$exe_update1->execute()) {
                        $flag = false;
                        $message .= "error la update stocki producti 
                        peshtr" . print_r($exe_update1->errorInfo());
                      }
               $update_stock = "UPDATE stock_tbl SET 
               quantitystock_karton=quantitystock_karton- 
               $kartontaza[$i], quantitystock_tak=quantitystock_tak- 
               $danataza[$i], total_quantity= 
               total_quantity-$hamwtaza[$i],last_update=$date, 
               pricekarton_instock=$pricekarton[$i], pricetak_instock= 
               $pricetdana[$i] where product_id=$product_id[$i]";
                 $exe_update = $dbh->prepare($update_stock);
                 if (!$exe_update->execute()) {
                  $flag = false;
                 $message .= "error la update stock";
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    
                $sql_update_company_loan = "update customer_load_tbl 
                set customer_id=?,sale_id=?,total_money=?,paid_money=? 
                 ,remain_money=?,total_remain=?,cus_pay_date=? where 
                cus_loan_id=?";
               $query_update_com = $dbh- 
               >prepare($sql_update_company_loan);
               $query_update_com->bindParam(1, $cus_name, 
               PDO::PARAM_STR);
               $query_update_com->bindParam(2, $sale_id, 
                PDO::PARAM_STR);
               query_update_com->bindParam(3, $total_all, 
               PDO::PARAM_STR);
               $query_update_com->bindParam(4, 
               $paid_money, PDO::PARAM_STR);
               $query_update_com->bindParam(5,$remain_purchase, 
               PDO::PARAM_STR);
               $query_update_com->bindParam(6, $loan_now, 
               PDO::PARAM_STR);
               $query_update_com->bindParam(7, $today, 
               PDO::PARAM_STR);
               $query_update_com->bindParam(8, $loan_id, 
               PDO::PARAM_STR);
               if (!$query_update_com->execute()) {
                $flag = false;
               $message .= "error la update customer loan" . 
                print_r($query_update_com->errorInfo());
                            }
                //end of all statements
                 if ($flag) {
                  $dbh->commit();
                    $message.="گۆرانکاری بەسەرکەوتووی ";
                  } else {
                    echo $message;
                    echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
                    //print_r($dbh->errorInfo()); 
                    //echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Ops.., 
                 Something wrong</div>';
                }
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                // Failed to insert the order into the database so 
                we rollback any changes
                throw $e;
            }
            echo $message;
          }
```

Please can anyone help I really appreciated it.

Comment: Curious, you went through the trouble of using prepared statements, yet in the end toss in `$sale_id` without any protection whatsoever... ???

Comment: @IncredibleHat, it's the same from there down, prepare is used without binds at all (a few exceptions)

Comment: @NigelRen Yeah seems so. I admit I did give up reading the code as its a mess of terrible indentation.

Comment: @IncredibleHat sorry for the styling, but please can you help me, when I have more than 57 row of data, update works fine but for the row 58  and above gives me undefined offset I don't why.